# Disable submit button until input fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my website link, Here i have been trying it using jquery code to enable/disable the button but could not succeed to achieve. You could inspect element to see the code please and output is off course there

Comment: Sorry your statement (`when I am selecting all the radio button values then also button in disabled mode.when I am selecting all the radio button the button should turn to enabled mode`) is not clear

Do you want to keep the submit button disabled till user does not select all radio options? And enable the submit button when all radio buttons values are selected. right?

Comment: I have edited your question and title. So any one else seeing it in future could get help easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tushar's solution is working perfectly. But I would recommend you to use formal/standard approach for validation.

Do not disable submit button. Just use `required` attribute for each radio button either in html like

```
<input id="input_5_0_1" class="form-radio" type="radio" required="required"
 name="customer_appointment" value="Good" />
```

or using js (its short cut way) like

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('form input').attr('required','required');        
});
```

[Demo on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0mLLo3L/1/)

This way you will not be able to submit until you fill all fields, though your button is not disabled.

However if you have to use button disable approach you can follow the above answer of @Tushar

**Edit** This solution works only with modern browsers who support html5.
Browsers other than mentioned in this link http://html5readiness.com/ (e.g internet explorer 4,5,6) do not support HTML5

Comment: You should also mention `browser support`

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var noOfRadio = 0;
    var names = [];

    $('form :radio').each(function () {
        if (!names[$(this).attr('name')]) {
            names[$(this).attr('name')] = 1;
            noOfRadio++;
        }
    });
    console.log(noOfRadio);
    $('form').on('change', ':radio', function () {
        console.log($('form').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length);
        if ($('form').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length === noOfRadio) {
            console.log('Enable');
            $('#input_2').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#input_2').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u0mLLo3L/

Comment: what about the second '>' in .each method?

Comment: @care567 Because `button` is not direct child of `form`. After removing `>` it will be applicable for all button inside form

Answer (score 0):

Why your Submit button is disabled or render as disabled. I checked in firebug and get this. Via firebug if I remove disable="disabled", it will work means post.

```
<div class="form-buttons-wrapper" style="text-align:left">
  <button id="input_2" class="form-submit-button form-submit-button-light_rounded" name="submit" type="submit"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

Comment: first it should be in disabled mode when user enters all the details then that button will enable.But Whenever I am filling all the details then also submit button in disabled mode?

Comment: I checked, it is disable, Yes, if all detail entered, it will enable and also post. Check at your end, where you enabled, still if you have issue , then simply, do not disabled any any time and click it.